# SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

Uso:

- Eclipse Oxygen
- SQL Server 2017
- SQL Management Studio 17.3
- Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server
- Java `jre1.8.0_151` x64
- Windows 10 x64

Cada vez que ejecuto mi programa recibo el siguiente error.

Error:

> SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.

He intentado:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637585/native-library-sqljdbc-auth-dll-already-loaded-in-another-classloader?answertab=votes#tab-top
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse/958074#958074
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277001/dll-missing-in-jdbc
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536608/this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087819/jdbc-sqlserverexception-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentic
- https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/364184/jdbc-throwing-sqlserverexception-this-driver-is-no.html
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2007/06/18/com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverexception-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication/
- Tengo `sqljdbc_auth` en "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin".
- Tengo `sqljdbc_auth` en "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib".
- Tengo `sqljdbc42` en mi proyecto y en Java Build Path.
- He intentado agregando `sqljdbc_auth` (x64 y x86) a
  "C:\Windows\System32".
- He intentado agregando `sqljdbc_auth` (x64 y x86) a
  "C:\Windows\SysWOW64".

Mi clase de conexión:

```
public class ConexionSQL {

    public String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    public String database = "industriaCine";
    public String hostname = "localhost";
    public String port = "1433";
    public String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + hostname + ":" + port + ";databaseName=" + database + ";integratedSecurity=true";

    public Connection conectarSQL() {
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("Conectado a la base de datos.");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: conectarSQL()", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        return conn;
    }
}
```

Nada me funciona, sigo recibiendo el mismo error.
Cómo puedo solucionarlo?.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68799/discussion-on-question-by-robert-gomez-sqlserverexception-this-driver-is-not-co).

Comment: ¿Has podido resolver el inconveniente? ¿Desististe?

Comment: @ElAsiduo No había podido resolver el problema luego de intentar miles soluciones. Al final, me cambié a MySQL y listo. A lo mejor hay versiones nuevas que corrigen el error?, ni idea...

Answer (score 1):

No se sabe si estamos ante un bug que ha vuelto a la vida. Lo cierto es que en 2005 ya se reportó este bug en Eclipse, y si revisas [este hilo](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=233565), verás que el problema aparece de forma intermitente al filo de los años (el último reporte es de febrero del 2017).

Como has dicho que has ido haciendo cosas y poniendo el archivo en diferentes carpetas, creo que llegó la hora de *hacer limpieza*. Para ello, borra donde quiera que hayas copiado el archivo `sqljdbc_auth.dll` y entonces vuelve a poner en práctica [lo que dice la documentación](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms378428(v=sql.105).aspx#Conexi%C3%B3n%20con%20la%20autenticaci%C3%B3n%20integrada) al respecto:

> Para usar la autenticación integrada, copie el archivo
>   `sqljdbc_auth.dll` en un directorio de la ruta del sistema de Windows en
>   que esté instalado el controlador JDBC.

La ruta sería: `<directorio de instalación>\sqljdbc_<version>\<language>\auth\`

Ten en cuenta lo que dicen las notas:

- Si está ejecutando una máquina virtual Java de (JVM, Java Virtual Machine) 32 bits, utilice el archivo sqljdbc_auth.dll en la carpeta x86, aun cuando la versión del sistema operativo sea la x64. Si está ejecutando una JVM de 64 bits en un procesador x64, utilice el archivo sqljdbc_auth.dll de la carpeta x64. Si está ejecutando una JVM de 64 bits en un procesador Itanium, utilice el archivo sqljdbc_auth.dll de la carpeta IA64.
- El controlador JDBC no admite la autenticación integrada cuando el controlador se ejecuta en sistemas operativos que no son de Windows. El controlador no proporciona funcionalidad para proporcionar las credenciales de autenticación de Windows, como el nombre de usuario y la contraseña al conectar con SQL desde sistemas operativos que no sean Windows. En tales casos, las aplicaciones deben usar la autenticación de SQL Server.

---

Teniendo en cuenta lo dicho más arriba, y visto que en tu entorno todo es compatible con 64bits, borra todo lo demás relativo a este asunto y [descarga de nuevo todo](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2017/03/31/jdbc-download-center-pages-and-repackaging/), los drivers del JDBC incluidos.

En cuanto al archivo `sqljdbc_auth.dll`, asegúrate de copiar en la carpeta indicada más arriba el archivo que corresponde:

```
JDBC 4.2 & JDBC 6.0

    auth
        x64
            sqljdbc_auth.dll <-----ESTE ES TU ARCHIVO
        x86
            sqljdbc_auth.dl
        jre7
            sqljdbc41.jar
        jre8
            sqljdbc42.jar    <-----ESTE ES TU ARCHIVO
    samples
    xa
        x64
            sqljdbc_xa.dll
        x86
            sqljdbc_xa.dll
```

Si haciendo todo eso, y todo lo que has hecho antes no se resuelve. Podríamos pensar que estamos ante un bug. Si lo reportas a Eclipse comentando en el mismo hilo del enlace ya indicado, podría ayudar a clarificar esa duda.

Si con la versión 6 no funciona, pasa entonces temporalmente a la versión 4.

En todo caso, asegúrate de que has limpiado todo, no sea que intente leer primero uno de los archivos que no funciona.